# How to hide Ruby file location when encountering error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I have been working in many Rails applications and during the period I have found many bugs but one thing really pissed me off is the error showing the Ruby file name in the terminal.

I tried to run

```
User.find(3)
```

in the Rails console, and, though I don't have more than one user record, it was obviously showing an error and I was aware of it. But the location part really messed up my terminal.

Here is the error log:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'=3
        from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_record/core.rb:150:in `find'
        from (irb):79
        from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
        from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
        from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:248:in `require'
        from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:248:in `block in require'
        from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:248:in `require'
        from /home/travis/tumpy/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `load'
        from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `block in load'
        from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `load'
        from /home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-
```

The solution I was expecting is to hide the location part and only display the error, showing

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'=3
```

Answer (score 2):

IRB has a [`back_trace_limit`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.4/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB/Context.html#back_trace_limit) option which defaults to `16`:

```
irb(main):001:0> IRB.CurrentContext.back_trace_limit
#=> 16
```

Setting it to `0` suppresses the entire backtrace:

```
irb(main):002:0> IRB.CurrentContext.back_trace_limit = 0
#=> 0
irb(main):003:0> User.find(0)
#  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 0 LIMIT 1
#ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with id=0
irb(main):004:0>
```

You can also pass this as a command line option:

```
$ rails console -- --back-trace-limit=0
```

Comment: Yes i have used pry and it tries to ignore much of backtraces but i want to remove all those backtraces in default rails engine. Not Pry

Comment: Ya it looks good for irb. But what if i want to implement in terminal instead of irb. For eg like while running rake db:migrate if i got some error i want to hide that. Is that possible?

Comment: Nopes. Can you brief it?

Comment: Terminals have two channels. `Stdout` and `Stderr`. You can hide ALL errors and only show normal outputs using `rake db:migrate 2>/dev/null`. But this will now hide every error. May serve your purpose.